# Angularjs filter to check if value is in array

Tags: angularjs

Posts have a title and an array of users who have liked the post:

```
{
  "title" : "Example Title",
  "likes" : ["User 1", "User 2", "User 3"]
}
```

I am displaying the "posts" like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
  <span ng-show="doesLike(post.likes)">Liked already</span>
  <span ng-hide="doesLike(post.likes)">Like this post</span>
</div>
```

and I have a function in my controller `doesLike()` that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the current user's username is in the array that is passed to the function. While this approach works can I achieve the same thing using a filter as I think this would be cleaner?

Comment: I would recommend a ng-if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is gonna be cleaner to have the logic in the view.
What will be cleaner is to don't call the `doesLike` function twice by digest cycle by using [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <span ng-switch="doesLike(post.likes)">
        <span ng-switch-when="true">
            Liked already
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-default>
            Like this post
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I like this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<span ng-if="doesLike(post.likes)">Liked already</span>
<span ng-if="!doesLike(post.likes)">Like this post</span>
```